# Copy file in multiple (variable) folders

Tags: files, cp, file-copy

I want to copy files in multiple subfolders with variable subfolder names.

Example:

```
mkdir rootdir
mkdir rootdir/dir1
mkdir rootdir/dir2
mkdir rootdir/dir3
touch rootdir/dir1/foo.txt
touch rootdir/dir2/foo.txt
touch rootdir/dir3/foo.txt
```

With known subfolder names, I can copy each file individually.

```
cp rootdir/dir1/foo.txt rootdir/dir1/bar.txt
cp rootdir/dir2/foo.txt rootdir/dir2/bar.txt
cp rootdir/dir3/foo.txt rootdir/dir3/bar.txt
```

But with an unknown number of subfolders with unknown subfolder names (I know the filenames), I can't do it anymore.

I can find the files...

```
ls ./**/foo.txt
find . -name foo.txt
```

... but I don't find the syntax which allows piping this information into cp (or into an alternative tool).

Comment: So you want to copy each file called `foo.txt` to a new file called `bar.txt` in each subdirectory recursively under `rootdir`?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few options:

```
find rootdir -type f -name foo.txt -execdir cp {} bar.txt \;
```

This searches for regular files called `foo.txt` anywhere in or under `rootdir`, and when one is found, `cp` is used to copy it to the name `bar.txt` in the same directory.  The `-execdir` option is non-standard but commonly implemented and will execute the given utility in the directory where the file was found.  The `{}` will be replaced by the found file's name.

Alternatively,

```
find rootdir -type f -name foo.txt -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        cp "$pathname" "${pathname%/*}/bar.txt"
    done' sh {} +
```

This does basically the same thing, but calls a short in-line `sh -c` script with batches of found `foo.txt` files.  The `cp` in the loop will copy each of these to the same directory as the found file, but with the filename part of the pathname replaced by `bar.txt`.

Using `**`, as you mention it in the question (assuming a `bash` shell):

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob dotglob

for pathname in rootdir/**/foo.txt; do
    cp "$pathname" "${pathname%/*}/bar.txt"
done
```

In `bash`, setting the `globstar` shell option enables the use of `**` for matching into subdirectories recurisvely, and `dotglob` will enable patterns to also match hidden names.  The `nullglob` shell option makes patterns disappear completely instead of remaining unexpanded if there is no match.

Again, but with `zsh` (explicitly asking for regular files and enabling the equivalent handling of the globbing as `dotglob` and `nullglob` would do for `bash`):

```
for pathname in rootdir/**/foo.txt(.ND); do
    cp $pathname $pathname:h/bar.txt
done
```

Here, `$pathname:h` would be the same as `$pathname` but with the filename portion of the pathname removed (`:h` as in "only the head", not the trailing bit).

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`, you can also use its `zmv` autoloadable function:

```
autoload -Uz zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv -C '(**/)(foo.txt)(#q.)' '${1}bar.txt'
```

Or:

```
zmv -C '**/foo.txt(#q.)' '$f:h/bar.txt'
```

Using `zmv` has the advantage over writing the loop manually that it has a few safety checks that prevent you from doing irreversible mistakes.